# My if, else, else if loop in C is not working?

Tags: c

Not sure if this is enough to go by, but this section of my code is not working, it keeps underlining the "else if" part saying it is expecting an expression, or a statement, then asks for a (. I can provide full code if needed I just feel like I am missing something obvious here. I've tried everything. Thanks!

```
    if (total <= AMT1)
    {
        taxes = RATE1 * total;
        printf("your tax rate is: %f\n", taxes);
    }

    else if
    {
        (total > 300 || total <= 450);
        taxes = RATE2 * total;
        printf("your tax rate is: %f\n", taxes);
    }


    else if
    {
        (total > 450);
        taxes = RATE3 * total;
        printf("your tax rate is: %f\n", taxes);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Treat yourself to [a good book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/253056).

Comment: You are indeed missing something fairly obvious. Might want to brush up on your C syntax a bit.

Comment: Remove the new line between `)` and `{` makes it neat, right?

Comment: @computerfreaker I have only been doing C for 8 weeks on and off. It's very late and I now see my mistake, placing the statement after the bracket instead of before, I'm sure you can understand that as a beginner, it isn't so "obvious" to me at first :)

Comment: @user3247128 I thought it might be something like that, hence the suggestion to brush up on syntax. I would have posted an answer but Rahn already had that covered. Don't worry too much about it, stuff like this happens to everyone.

Comment: Stop defacing your questions after you got your answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
if (total <= AMT1)
{
    taxes = RATE1 * total;
    printf("your tax rate is: %f\n", taxes);
}

else if(total > 300 || total <= 450)
{
    taxes = RATE2 * total;
    printf("your tax rate is: %f\n", taxes);
}


else if(total > 450)
{
    taxes = RATE3 * total;
    printf("your tax rate is: %f\n", taxes);
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH I FEEL SO STUPID. THANK YOU. YOU GENIUS :D